# Pandas get from pandas.core.frame.Pandas object

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas.core.frame.Pandas object and need to return a value from it based on its attribute name. The below code works

```
val = pandas_object.attr_name
```

However, the attribute I need to get changes, so I need something dynamic like

```
val = pandas_object.get(attr_name)
```

The pandas objecet does not have a getter function as I get the below error

```
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Other pandas classes seem to have that. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.get.html

I cant find much documentation on this type oaf pandas object. Is there a way to get the values similar to .get()?

This is the object I have

```
Pandas(Index=0, Time_USec=Timestamp('2016-12-19 09:05:00.683243'), OrderId=0, Status='New')
```

When I follow the adive to use **getattr** I get the below error

```
print event.__getattr__("Time_USec")
```

AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another solution I stumbled across is

```
pandas_object.__getattribute__(attr_name)
```

Seems to be more natural/intuitive than the

```
pandas_object.__dict__[attr_name]
```

Unfortunately, as opposed to .get this method allows not to set a default value

Comment: Re _this method allows not to set a default value_, you can just try this: `pandas_object.__dict__.get(attr_name, None)`, which will return `None` or whatever you put in the second slot as the default. Worked at least for me.

Answer (score 10):

The Pandas class you mention is actually a dynamically created *named tuple* class (see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7b92e7ee47fa3024aa5bc4fb3518717157c88dcc/pandas/core/frame.py#L905)). By default the class is named "Pandas" but you can actually name it whatever you want like so:

```
my_tuples = list(df.itertuples(name='Whatever'))
assert isinstance(my_tuples[0], tuple)
assert my_tuples[0].__class__.__name__ == 'Whatever'
```

As you can see from the [official documentation for named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), you can convert them to dictionaries like so:

```
some_object = some_namedtuple._asdict()
val = some_object.get(attr_name)
```

But a more Pythonic way of retrieving an attribute would be to just simply use the built-in [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function which also works with any other Python object:

```
val = getattr(some_namedtuple, attr_name)
```

Comment: pandas_object.__dict__ did not work in pandas==1.3.4 but pandas_object._asdict() and this one works. in case if want to get default value, use getattr(pandas_object, 'attr_name', None).

Answer (score 3):

Example input:

```py
row = Pandas(Index=0, OrderId=0, Status='New')
```

To access `Status`, you can use:

```py
row.Status
# or
getattr(row, 'Status')
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `__dict__` attribute.

Consider the following example

```
attr_name = 'ABCIndex'
pd.core.frame.algos.__dict__[attr_name]

pandas.types.generic.ABCIndex
```

Comment: I still get AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: The object I have is not a DataFrame or a Series.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working exactly like I was looking for